# How to Display Saved Images in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-request

I am trying to show stored images in `img` element. I have saved an image by using a Laravel built-in function.

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('avatars');
```

According to the above script, the images are saving to:

**Storage > app > avatars**

I also tried saving them here:

**Storage > app > public > avatars**

Afterward, I used the Artisan command: `php artisan storage:link`

And then in the front end:

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/'.$Product->image) }}" width="30" height="30"/>
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$Product->image) }}" width="30" height="30"/>
<img src="{{ asset($Product->image) }}" width="30" height="30"/>
<img src="{{ asset('public/storage/'.$Product->image) }}" width="30" height="30"/>
```

However, the image is still not displayed. Can someone kindly let me know where I'm wrong so that I can fix it? I would appreciate that.

Comment: After `php artisan storage:link` use this to show image: `<img src="{{ url('storage/avatars/'.$Product->image) }}" alt="" title="" />
`

Comment: are you sure your file is uploaded on storage folder ? if yes then did you find out actually where the file is ?

Comment: @HirenGohel I tried your instruction but it does not works

Comment: @ScriptLover: Be sure that image is in dir of `storage/app/public/avatars'`

Comment: @EmtiazZahid yes files are exactly at same location which I mentioned as above

Comment: Also, what is included `$Product->image` ? Is it only image name??

Comment: @HirenGohel no, it has avatar folder name `avatars/naDlln02BTM8CwvRoT5WS4flQpBozVbXu7Qtnmin.png`

Comment: So, `naDlln02BTM8CwvRoT5WS4flQpBozVbXu7Qtnmin.png` image is in `storage/app/public/avatars` directory right?

Comment: @HirenGohel Yes exactly

Comment: What is result of `$Product->image` ?

Comment: @HirenGohel the result is `avatars/naDlln02BTM8CwvRoT5WS4flQpBozVbXu7Qtnmin.png` of `$Product->image`

Comment: Got it now. Use only this: `<img src="{{ url('storage/'.$Product->image) }}" alt="" title="" /> `

Comment: @HirenGohel `$Product->image` result is `public/avatars/Mb1houwdhM38eP3acnP2xHy6koGuMClkaoIcoIMb.jpeg` and image is inside `storage/app/public/avatars`

Comment: @HirenGohel and above suggested script does not works

Comment: Once remove `public` from `$Product->image` and then check.

Comment: @HirenGohel but it is adding dynamically from laravel script

Comment: @HirenGohel yes it is working after removing `public` but how can I prevent to store in db because it is storing dynamically

Comment: Try this: `<img src="<?php echo asset("storage/$Product->image")?>"></img>`

Comment: Got it working now?

Comment: @HirenGohel yes but I need to remove `public` from url after uploading, so I need to dynamic solution

Comment: @ScriptLover: I've posted my answer below, please check it!

Comment: @ScriptLover:Have you checked it?